# Getting units from ISpatialReference of ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, coordinate-system

How do I get the units (meter/feet) from an ISpatialReference object in ArcObjects?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Linear units can be obtained from the spatial reference only if it is a projected coordinate system. So, you need to cast the spatial reference to [IProjectedCoordinateSystem](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IProjectedCoordinateSystem_Interface/002m000002qv000000/) and access its [IProjectedCoordinateSystem.CoordinateUnit](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/002m/002m000002z5000000.htm) property.

But if the spatial reference is a geographic coordinate system, its units are angular and accessed similarly through [IGeographicCoordinateSystem.CoordinateUnit](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/002m/002m000001r3000000.htm).

Comment: +1 The ILinearUnit.MetersPerUnit property can also save you from writing a lot of code.

Answer (score 0):

```
IFields fields = featureClass.Fields;
        ISpatialReference spatialReference = fields.get_Field(fields.FindField(featureClass.ShapeFieldName)).GeometryDef.SpatialReference;
        if (spatialReference is IProjectedCoordinateSystem)
        {
            IProjectedCoordinateSystem projectedCoordinateSystem = (IProjectedCoordinateSystem)spatialReference;
            return projectedCoordinateSystem.CoordinateUnit.Name;
        }
        if (spatialReference is IGeographicCoordinateSystem)
        {
            IGeographicCoordinateSystem geographicCoordinateSystem = (IGeographicCoordinateSystem)spatialReference;
            return geographicCoordinateSystem.CoordinateUnit.Name;
        }
```